# Apache 500 server fault causes a different vhost to be sent to the browser

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an Apache server with three virtual hosts. The first is just to establish a default vhost and just displays the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default" page. The other two are real web sites. One has been working for a while now. The other is brand new and not entirely functional yet.

The problem I'm having is that when the new site generates a 500 error (there isn't any data in the database yet), the other real vhost's content is delivered to the browser.

The default vhost is defined in apache.conf.
The other two vhosts have there own configuration files and have been a2ensite'd
All three vhosts are currently using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

They have different values for their ServerName parameters.
They have different values for the DocumentRoot directives.
The older site has rewrite enabled (it's a WordPress site).
The new site does not have rewrite enabled.
I haven't been able to find anything useful in any of the logs.

```
curl -I http://...
```

Works as expected.

- Environment: Ububtu 18.04
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.2.10
- Symfony 4.2

Suggestions would be welcome.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my browser, not the server.

As I was typing the bit about the curl command working, I realized that it was probably a browser issue and cleared my browser cache.

Yep that was it.